# AWS boto3 attribute_not_exists

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

```
currDBraw = table.scan(
  FilterExpression=Attr('purebetId').gt(0) & "attribute_not_exists(ouline)",
  ProjectionExpression="event,homeTeam,awayTeam,startDate,purebetId" 
)
```

Im new to aws and boto3, with this, i get

AND operation cannot be applied to value attribute_not_exists(ouline) of type <class 'str'> directly

and im unsure of what it means or what i can do

Answer (score 0):

attribute_not_exists is a conditional expression used only in update/insert operations

```
ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(something)
```

What you need to do is just compare to null

```
currDBraw = table.scan(
  FilterExpression=Attr('purebetId').gt(0) & "outline = null",
  ProjectionExpression="event,homeTeam,awayTeam,startDate,purebetId" 
)
```

Comment: I still get the same error when changing to this...?